# allocating array and assigning values from a function C

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers, segmentation-fault

### C question

Hi,

I am passing a double pointer to a function to allocate a double array and initialise the array inside the function with lets say 10.10;

I do the following but get segmentation fault when I access the array in main;

```
void function(double **array, int size){

    *array = (double*) malloc(size * sizeof(double)); 
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<size;i++){
    *array[i] = 10.10;
    }


}

int main(){

    double *array = NULL;

    function(&array,20);
    printf("array[0] = %lg\n",array[0]);// here is where I get segmentation fault


}
```

Any help ?

Comment: "here is where I get segmentation fault" is not on the line where you get the segfault.

Comment: as a sidenote: the cast to `double*` is a) unnecessary, and b) wrong, because what you really have there is `double**`

Comment: @Andreas: you're right about (a) but not (b) ;-)

Comment: @AndreasGrapentin It's rather wrong because it's unsafe.

Comment: @PaulR whoops, you're right of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
*array[i]
```

doesn't mean what you think it does (look it up using a [C operator precedence table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C++)).

Instead of unreadable, ugly and confusing (yes, it just confused you) code, use a temporary variable (***and do not for the love of God cast the return value of malloc!***):

```
void function(double **array, int size)
{
    if (array == NULL) return;

    double *tmp = malloc(size * sizeof(*tmp)); 
    if (tmp == NULL) {
        *array = NULL;
        return;
    }

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        tmp[i] = 10.10;
    }

    *array = tmp;
}
```

Also, `return 0;` from `main()`. Really.

Comment: Perhaps a `*array = NULL` in the event of `malloc` failure would not go amiss.

Comment: @EdHeal And a check for the address of the output argument being valid (non-NULL) as well :)

Comment: return 0 from main() is good style, but not necessary since C99.

Comment: @Lundin I didn't suggest it because it was necessary, but because it's good practice, as you suggested.

Answer (score 4):

You have fallen foul of operator precedence.

Change:

```
for(i=0;i<size;i++){
    *array[i] = 10.10;
}
```

to:

```
for(i=0;i<size;i++){
    (*array)[i] = 10.10;
}
```

Note that if you had compiled with warnings enabled (e.g. `gcc -Wall ...`) your compiler would have caught this for you. **Always** compile with warnings enabled and **always** pay heed to, understand and fix any warnings.